# Show that $\int_{-x}^xf=2\int_0^xf$ implies that $f$ is even.

Tags: integration, proof-verification

Please tell me whether the following proof works:

> $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that $\int_{-x}^xf=2\int_0^xf~\forall~x\in\mathbb R.$ Show that $f$ is an even function.

Choose $c>0.$ It suffices to show that $f(c)=f(-c).$ By hypothesis $$\int_{-c}^cf=2\int_0^cf\implies\int_{-c}^0f=\int_0^cf$$

So for $n\in\mathbb Z^+,$ $$\int_{c-c/n}^cf=\int_{-c}^{-c+c/n}f\tag{1}$$

Due to the continuity of $f$ on $[c-c/n,c],[-c,-c/n]~\exists~x_n\in[c/n,c],~x_n'\in[-c,-c/n]$ such that $$\int_{c-c/n}^cf=f(x_n)\cdot c/n\\\int_{-c}^{-c+c/n}f=f(x_n')\cdot c/n$$

So by $(1),$$$f(x_n)=f(x_n')~\forall~n$$

Now since $x_n\to c,x_n'\to-c$ and $f$ is continuous at $c,-c$ we have $$\lim f(x_n)=\lim f(x_n')\implies f(c)=f(-c).$$

Answer (score 1):

Your approach using the mean value theorem for integration is fine. A more elegant approach is using the fundamental theorem of calculus. Just take the derivative on both sides of the equation
$$ \int_{-x}^x f(\xi)\,\mathrm d\xi = 2\int_0^x f(\xi)\,\mathrm d\xi$$
and obtain
$$ f(-x) + f(x) = 2f(x),$$
which is equivalent to $f(-x)=f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

I this your proof works. I have an alternative way:
Define $F(x)=\int_0^xf(t)dt$. Using the fundamental theorem of calculus, the condition becomes $F(x)-F(-x)=2F(x) \iff F(-x)=-F(x)$. Since the derivative of odd function is an even function, this follows $F^\prime(x)=f(x)$ is en even function.